# How to exit OOBE-Mode in cloned Virtual Machines?

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

I have some Virtual Machines with Windows Server 2013 R2 which are cloned.
Now these clones cannot register to our WSUS. WindowsUpdate.log tells this:

```
OOBE is in progress, so cannot perform Accelerated Install
```

I already tried this...

```
set-itemproperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\' -Name IsOOBEInProgress -Value 0
```

...but after reboot this value is set back to "1".

Now I need to know how I can exit this OOBE-Mode.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sysprep /oobe /shutdown (VMWARE WM / Windows server 2012 R2)
I just resorted to this on a production web webserver that has been annoying me for a while. This I am guessing was the cause of other problems as well eg Tasks starting in a queued state.
Bit the bullet as I had to sort the other issues out.
MAKE SURE YOU KNOW THE LOCAL ADMIN PASSWORD!!!!!
MAKE SURE YOU KNOW THE LOCAL ADMIN PASSWORD!!!!!
Will need to reapply your region etc when it boots back up.
Will need to add machine back into the domain.
My issues are resolved - wish I'd done this a year ago as had to run the powershell Wupdate scripts - if I remembered - though it isnt showing the updates I installed via this method - but I know it was relatively up to date)